# insert file image with name of the file

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4

when I insert an image file in my project, The image is inserted correctly in content image folder but the name of the file is renamed with series of caracters like 080ed...

And after when I try to show image in html code it s not ok.

tks for help

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Tretouche.fichierphoto != null && Tretouche.fichierphoto.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileExtensionApplication = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Tretouche.fichierphoto.FileName);
                // generating a random guid for a new file at server for the uploaded file
                string newFile = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtensionApplication;
                // getting a valid server path to save
                string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("Content\\image"), newFile);

                if (Tretouche.fichierphoto.FileName != String.Empty)
                {
                    Tretouche.fichierphoto.SaveAs(filePath);
                    Tretouche.SRCphoto = "\\image\\" + "idclientidcmd" + Tretouche.Nomphoto.ToString() + fileExtensionApplication;
                }
            }
            db.TRetouches.Add(Tretouche);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: `string newFile = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` - so what'd you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
string newFile = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtensionApplication;
```

This line renames the image with a NewGuid. NewGuid will generate a random string of characters containing letters and numbers

**From MSDN**

```
using System;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Guid g;
        // Create and display the value of two GUIDs.
        g = Guid.NewGuid();
        Console.WriteLine(g);
        Console.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}

/*
This code example produces the following results:

0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e
7c9e6679-7425-40de-944b-e07fc1f90ae7

*/
```

Please also take a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) references about NewGuid